# Definition of bounded in a metric space - confirmation

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

Is the following definition of a bounded metric space correct?

> $(M,d)$ is bounded if $\exists a \in M, r > 0$ such that $M = B(a,r)$.

Looking around on the internet I instead see $M \subset B(a,r)$.

Comment: Since $M$ may not be a perfect ball, we require instead that $M$ can be contained in a ball, which corresponds to the requirement that $M\subseteq B(a,r)$.

Comment: For example, think of the set $\{ (x, y) \in R^2 : -1\leq |x+y| \leq 1 \}$, which looks like a tilted square centred at the origin. This set is bounded, but is not equal to a disk for any $a$ or $r$. It is contained in the unit disk however!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I'm really looking for some "authoritative" confirmation of the definition since your example depends on this (as Milo below points out, the definitions seem to differ for the metric itself and a subset of the metric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent. In particular, since a ball is defined as
$$B(a,r)=\{x\in M:d(x,a)<r\}$$
it is trivial that we have $B(a,r)\subseteq M$ for any $a$ and $r$. Knowing this, the statement that $M\subseteq B(a,r)$ implies that $B(a,r)=M$ since $\subseteq$ is an antisymmetric relation.

However, one might note that if you want to define a bounded subset $S\subseteq M$, then you would write $S\subseteq B(a,r)$ rather than $S=B(a,r)$, since the ball would be taking place in $M$ rather than intrinsically $S$.

---

The definition $M\subseteq B(a,r)$ is a good definition for a metric space or subset thereof being bounded. This coincides with the intuition people want to capture by boundedness, though it is equivalent to other definitions. Moreover, in the definition $M=B(a,r)$, one could easily forget that the ball on the right hand side of the equation must be taken with respect to $M$ and not to some larger space, where writing $M\subseteq B(a,r)$ does not allow one to make such a mistake.

Comment: Ah, I made the assumption that the definition of a bounded subset would be the same as that of the metric. Would it ever make any sense to define it the same way?

Comment: @IrregularUser Defining "bounded" as $M\subseteq B(a,r)$ is entirely reasonable in both the case of $M$ as a subspace of a bigger metric space, or $M$ as the whole space. This is certainly what people mean by bounded, even if other things are equivalent. As a bonus, where the definition $M=B(a,r)$ gives you a great opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot if you forget that the ball on the left is a ball with respect to $M$, the definition $M\subseteq B(a,r)$ removes the temptation.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "the ball on the left"?

Comment: @IrregularUser Er, I meant "right" - the ball on the right side of the equation $M=B(a,r)$ is taken with respect to $M$.

Comment: I thought so but I just wanted to confirm that. It's just that in my "literature" (rather, notes from class) we use $=$ rather than $\subseteq$ in the definition where $M$ is the whole space, which is why when we started talking about subsets of the whole metric space I wanted to seek some sort of confirmation. I do agree that $\subseteq$ gives a more student friendly definition. Thanks very much for also giving a comparison on both equivalent definitions. Would you mind adding your comment to the answer?

Comment: @IrregularUser I added it to the answer. (I might say that it's probably more than a student friendly definition - I think the definition $M=B(a,r)$, though equivalent, really looks weird and takes a bit more effort to understand the intuitive meaning than $M\subseteq B(a,r)$)